# Altium : how to delete vias and path that are outside of board

Tags: altium, component-selection

This might be a stupid question but I moved a room, resulting in some vias and path in negative coordinates. You can see below a 3D view. I would like to delete 
them but in 2D mode, I can't zoom out to see the elements that are in negative coordinates. So I can't select them...

I tried to flip the view but it's not better.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: You want to know how to select the components that have gone on the negative x-direction, so that you could delete them? Or I'm understanding it wrong?

Comment: Try a `Ctrl-A` ("select all") and then `E-M-S` ("Edit -> Move -> Selection"), click on any part of the board and try dragging in the desired direction to bring the off-screen components back in.

Comment: @Sachin: Yes, you're right

Comment: @Julien Glad to hear it! For future reference, I HIGHLY recommend moving your relative origin much further away from the absolute origin (bottom left of the screen) to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Julien Added the above as an official answer.

Comment: You can also filter and select using a query or find them in the PCB List panel.

Comment: @Manu3l0us It can be pretty difficult to select specific vias using queries, and sifting through the PCB List would be very impractical

Comment: @DerStrom8: There's no need to sift through the list in this case. You just sort by X or Y coordinate and due to the fact that those vias have very negative coordinates, they are easy to pick. The advantage of this is that it will normally also work when Ctrl-A doesn't. Had that kind of trouble back in Altium 13.

Comment: @Manu3l0us Fair point =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a Ctrl-A ("select all") and then E-M-S ("Edit -> Move -> Selection"), click on any part of the board and try dragging in the desired direction to bring the off-screen components back in. For future reference, I HIGHLY recommend moving your relative origin much further away from the absolute origin (bottom left of the screen) to avoid this issue.